# Using polar coordinates to sketch phase portrait

Tags: dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

I am trying to use polar coordiantes to sketch the phase portrait of the following system,

$$x'=xy-x^2y+y^3$$
$$ y'=y^2+x^3-xy^2$$

I know the formula for polar coordinates is the following,

$$r'=\frac{xx'+yy'}{r}$$
$$\theta'=\frac{y'x-yx'}{r^2}$$

But how do I change my system into these polar coordinates and then draw the phase portait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  r' &= \frac{xx'+yy'}{r} \\
  &= \frac{x(xy-x^2y+y^3)+y(y^2+x^3-xy^2)}{r} \\
  &= \frac{x^2y-x^3y+xy^3+y^3+x^3y-xy^3}{r} \\
  &= \frac{y(x^2+y^2)}{r} \\
  &= r^2\sin \theta \\
  \theta' &= \frac{xy'-xy'}{r} \\
  &= \frac{x(y^2+x^3-xy^2)-y(xy-x^2y+y^3)}{r^2} \\
  &= \frac{xy^2+x^4-x^2y^2-xy^2+x^2y^2-y^4}{r^2} \\
  &= \frac{(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)}{r^2} \\
  &= r^2(\cos^2 \theta-\sin^2 \theta) \\
  &= r^2\cos 2\theta
\end{align*}

> Note that the vector field is $$
> \begin{align*}
>   \mathbf{A}(r,\theta) &= r' \mathbf{e}_r+r\theta' \mathbf{e}_{\theta} \\
>   &= r^2\sin \theta \, \mathbf{e}_r+r^3\cos 2\theta \, \mathbf{e}_{\theta}
> \end{align*}$$

Comment: Hence $$r'=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos2\theta}\theta'$$ which can be integrated into
$$r-r_0=\int_{\cos\theta_0}^{\cos\theta}\frac{dv}{1-2v^2}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\ln\left|\frac{1+\sqrt2\cos\theta}{1-\sqrt2\cos\theta}\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt2\cos\theta_0}{1+\sqrt2\cos\theta_0}\right|$$ IOW, every solution stays confined on a curve of equation $$\frac{1+\sqrt2\cos\theta}{1-\sqrt2\cos\theta}\cdot e^{2\sqrt2r}=K$$